# UPDATE 2 columns in all rows using VALUES() array

Tags: mysql, set

I cant quite figure out the correct way to do the following:

1.) I have a fullname column 
2.) I need to split that fullname column into first & last name chunks 
3.) I need to insert the 'split' data into their respective columns (which are currently empty and in the same table)

I couldnt figure out how to do it in one query, so I broke it down into steps:

1.) got my split data (first/last strings)

```
SELECT fullname, SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,' ',1) AS fname, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,'.',2),' ',-1) AS lname FROM tablename;
```

which gave my fname & lname sub-strings..

I erroneously tried this:

```
INSERT INTO paypalRegistration (firstname, lastname) VALUES
("xxxx", "xxx"),
("yyy", "yyy"),
("zzz", "zzz"),...etc..
```

which just insert things into NEW rows.. (and didnt update the current rows [with blank columns] already in the table)

So I then tried this:

```
UPDATE paypalRegistration SET(firstname, lastname) VALUES ("xxxx", "xxx"),
("yyy", "yyy"), ("zzz", "zzz"),...etc..
```

but got an error..

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(firstname, lastname) VALUES ("xxxx", "xxx").....

So at this point, my question is two-fold.

1.) How can I do this in 1 query?

2.) At the point I'm at, what is the correct way to update 2+ columns with unique values like I have above?

Update:

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
UPDATE myTable SET firstname=SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,' ',1), lastname=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,'.',2),' ',-1);
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is correct. or give some comments at least if it is not the answer that you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your table name is **paypalRegistration**
This table **paypalRegistration** has the following columns:

1. id INT PRIMARY KEY
2. fullName VARCHAR
3. firstName VARCHAR
4. lastName VARCHAR

I expect to have id column already in your table **paypalRegistration** as explained above.
Now, you can do this SQL:

```
UPDATE paypalRegistration x 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullName,' ',1) AS fname,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullName,'.',2),' ',-1) AS lname
  FROM paypalRegistration
) y ON y.id=x.id 
SET x.firstName = y.fname, x.lastName = y.lname;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just getting back to work.

Actually I worked out a simple 1 liner query that does both split & insert..(set)...  looks to be very similar to what you posted as well:

    `UPDATE myTable SET firstname=SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,' ',1), lastname=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,'.',2),' ',-1);`

I'll accept your answer though as it was the only one. :)